# PHP regex undifined offset when used in function

Tags: php, regex

I have a string consists of multiple lines. I am getting this string from imap (as an email body). I get this string as follows:

```
$mail_body = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$msgno,1);
```

My regex is:

```
preg_match("/HEX}(.*).php/", $string, $matches);
```

If I describe this string manually like:

```
$_string = "It is too long therefore I do not paste it here"
```

And If I do that:

```
preg_match("/HEX}(.*).php/",$_string,$matches);
$new_string = $matches[1];
echo $new_string;
```

It works perfectly.

But when I passed string to a function in same class:

$this->some_funtion($mail_body);

It gives me an error although I am doing the same thing in function:

```
preg_match("/HEX}(.*).php/",$_string,$matches);
$new_string = $matches[1];
echo $new_string;
```

Error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Why should it happen? I am doing the very same thing!

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

```
private function get_directory_path($string = '')
{   
    preg_match("/HEX}(.*).php/", $string, $matches);
    $new_string = $matches[1];
    echo $new_string;
}
```

I pass parameter as follows:

```
$mail_body = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$msgno,1.2);
if(!strlen($mail_body)>0){
$mail_body = imap_fetchbody($mbox,$msgno,1);
}
$this->get_directory_path($mail_body);
```

Comment: `}` is a special symbol; it's the closing delimiter for defining a range quantifier.  You need to escape it if you want to look for that as a literal value `\}`

Comment: As to your actual `Notice`, it's because your regex is returning false (no match) so `$matches[1]` doesn't exist, and you're attempting to reference it

Comment: @CrayonViolent In this special case, PCRE is smart enough to match a literal `}`

Comment: @CrayonViolent but it works perfectly when I put that string in a variable?

Comment: @HamZa aah is it? TIL.. curiozity in any case, see my 2nd comment about the actual error. You'll want to do `if (isset($matches[1])) $new_string = $matches[1];`

Comment: @CrayonViolent: In most regex engines, the closing square bracket `]` and curly brace `}` can be used unescaped as literals as long as there's no preceding opening bracket.

Comment: @curiozity long story short: always enclose your `preg_match()` in an `if` statement: `if(preg_match(...)){ echo $matches[1];}else{ echo 'no match';}`

Comment: Do a var_dump of `$_string` in the `$this->some_function` method to make sure it is what you are expecting. I would assume that you are not defining the `$_string` as an argument in the method.

Comment: @curiozity you need to check if it [isset](http://www.php.net/isset) before attempting to use it.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I defined $string as an argument and $this->some_function sending true parameter I var_dumped it

Comment: Just a side note: in your regex `.php` will match any character in front of `php` because `.` is the wildcard symbol. Escape it as `\.php`.

Comment: So your argument is `$string` and preg_match is using `$_string`?

Comment: @CrayonViolent the string what I attemp to read is "set" in $pattern but it returns undefined offset ?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn it is written correct in my function

Comment: Well then the pattern isn't matching. You didn't post the entire function so we have to just assume and guess as to how it is written. And by "truely" I'm assuming you mean "correct".

Comment: @JonathanKuhn no more assuming I edited the question and yes you are right It must be "correct"! Sorry

Comment: Maybe `if(!strlen($mail_body)>0){` should be `if(strlen($mail_body)<=0){`. I believe `!strlen($mail_body)` is evalaluated first to a boolean value, converted to an integer and then compared to `> 0`.

Comment: I wrote it the way you've said. But unfortunately still same. "Undefined offset"

Comment: You should do a `var_dump($string)` inside of `get_directory_path` to make sure what is passed in is right and post the result.

Comment: Actually it does pass the string value to function. Something is going wrong in function. As I indicated above when I put the same string (what I passed as a argument) in a variable. It works!

Comment: There are several things that might make the pattern not match. Newlines, spaces and tabs being the biggest problem because when you echo out to the screen and copy/paste to test they don't copy. Perhaps echo out the `$mail_body` variable inside of `<pre>` tags before passing it to the function or echo and view the source.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn that was very true! When I echo it in <pre> tags I saw newlines, line spaces etc. Could you please say how I can escape them?

Comment: Well the easy way is to add the `s` modifier so that the dot (`.`) character matches newlines. So `/pat{2}ern/s`

Comment: Ok I got it fixed by adding "/s" thank you @JonathanKuhn you've been very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that might make the pattern not match. Newlines, spaces and tabs being the biggest problem because when you echo out to the screen and copy/paste to test they don't copy. Perhaps echo out the `$mail_body` variable inside of `<pre>` tags before passing it to the function or echo and view the source.

The easy way to fix it is to add the s modifier so that the dot (`.`) character matches newlines. So `/pat{2}ern/s`. But that might not give you the result you want. Without a full output of the string and what you expect from it (or what you are using it for), it wouldn't be possible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('dataconn.php');
    $result=mysql_query("select * from product");


while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<p>$row[Product_Name]</p>";

                echo "<p>$row[Product_Quantity]</p>";
                echo "<p><a href=\"payment.php?action=add&pid=$row[Product_ID]&qty=1\">Add To Cart</a></p>";






        }
?>
<a href="logout2.php">logout</a>

/*--add to cart page--*/
<?php 
/* ----------- ADD TO CART PAGE ----------------*/
include("dataconn.php");
$product_id = isset($_GET['pid']) ? $_GET['pid'] : null; 
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null; //the action
$quantity=isset($_GET['qty']) ? $_GET['qty'] : null; 
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>View Cart</title>


</head>
<body>

<?php 
$customer_id=$_SESSION['customer_id'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from product");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
switch($action) 
{ 
//decide what to do 
case "add":
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;


break;
case "remove":
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = 0;
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]);
    header("Location: payment.php");//if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
break;
case "empty":
    unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
    header("Location: payment.php");
break;
}
//------- for checkout ---------
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && $_SESSION['cart']) { 
    $total = 0;
    echo "<form name='cart' method='POST' action=''>";
    echo "<table border=\"1\" padding=\"3\" width=\"100%\" class=\"data-container\">"; 
     echo "<td colspan=\"4\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"payment.php?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\"><img src=\"image/delete.png\"/></a></td>";

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) 
    { 
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM product WHERE Product_ID = %d;", $product_id); 
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $itemsInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $cost = $itemsInfo["Product_Price"] * $quantity;
            $total = $total + $cost; //add to the total cost
            echo "<tr>";

            //show this information in table cells
            echo "<td align=\"center\">".$itemsInfo["Product_Name"]."</td>";
            //along with a 'remove' link next to the quantity - which links to this page, but with an action of remove, and the id of the current product
            echo "<td align=\"center\">$quantity </td>";
            echo "<td align=\"center\">RM $cost</td>";
             echo "<td align=\"center\"><a href=\"payment.php?action=remove&pid=$product_id\"><img src=\"image/remove.png\"/></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    //show the total
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan=\"2\" ></td>";
    echo "<td align=\"center\">Total</td>";
    echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\">RM $total</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
    }

    ?>
    <br>
    <div>
    <span style="margin-left: 88%"><a href="product3.php"><input type="submit" name="shopping_more"  class="custom-button" value="Back To Shopping"/></a></span>
    </div>


    </html>
```